# Is there a way to find percentage of non-zero vs zero values in one column?

Tags: sql

I'm supposed to find the percentage of people having received aid.

I'm assuming the best way to do this is find the number rows who received 0 aid, and the number of rows that have a greater than 0 value, create two variables for those and divide accordingly to find the percentage.  It's been a while since I've worked with sql so this is challenging me.

```
select
    rprawrd_aidy_code as year,
    sum(rprawrd_accept_amt)

from
    rprawrd

where
    rprawrd_aidy_code = '1819'

group by
    rprawrd_aidy_code
```

This only gives me a total of the amount of aid provided for the year in question.  I need to figure out the total rows that received vs the total that didnt.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ... as tabular text

Comment: whats a proper data sample?  and I did list the expected result.  the average of received vs non received aid

Comment: I'm confused, you have `rprawrd_aidy_code as year` but you're setting it equal to 1819 in your `WHERE` clause. Is that supposed to be the year 1819? Also, what's in the `rprawrd_accept_amt` column for those that didn't receive any aid? Is it a `0` or `null`?

Answer (score 3):

If the only output you need from your script is that ratio, there are a few ways to go about this one:

```
WITH cte (awrd) AS(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN rprawrd_accept_amt > 0 THEN 1.0
        ELSE 0.0
        END awrd
    FROM rprawrd
    WHERE rprawrd_ady_code = '1819'
    )
SELECT SUM(awrd)/COUNT(awrd)
FROM cte
```

This will get you the percentage of people who received an award, but if you need to know the amounts as well you'll have to approach it differently.